# REST API design: Keep a unique item in a collection

Tags: rest, api-design

Suppose I have some REST APIs to manage a user's registered emails. Users can register multiple emails, but only one of them can be primary.

Suppose this is the API that can be used to change email attributes. We can use it to change if an email is a primary email:

```
PATCH /members/:member_id/emails/:email_id
{
    "is_primary": false
}
```

Suppose a user has registered the primary and secondary email addresses and needs to exchange the primary and secondary emails. A nature UI design pops up a dialog showing all the email addresses, and the user uses the check box or dropdown list to make the exchange and press the OK button. The question is how the UI translates the operation.

Because the endpoint only supports updating a single email at a time, the UI must first change the secondary email to primary and then change one of the primary emails to secondary. Hopefully, we will allow multiple primary emails.

Should the updating operation target the email set, not a single email address? What's a better design? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe UI re-renders the complete email list component ?